# Showing Multiple Beans error , Even on providing Specific Bean in the constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create a bean of a Rest Controller ("demoController") , it is having a dependency of Coach interface. I am having two coaches Football and Cricket. I had made a configuration class in which i had defined the specific coach that needs to be called in constructor , still it is showing the same error.

Action: Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed

Is it an autoWired problem??

here's the code

```
package com.example.Spring2.interafaces;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class demoController {
//    define a constructor
    private Coach myCoach;
//    make a constructor
    @Autowired
    public demoController(Coach MyCoach){
        this.myCoach=MyCoach;
    }

    @GetMapping("/demo")
    public String demo(){
        return myCoach.dailyWorkout();
    }


}
```

```
package com.example.Spring2.interafaces;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public Coach setFcoach(){
        return new FootballCoach();
    }
    @Bean
    public Coach setCricketCoach(){
        return new CricketCoach();
    }
    @Bean
    public demoController setDemoController(){
        return new demoController( setFcoach());
    }
}
```

I tried to instantiate the specific class in Configuerations, but it still is showing the same.

I am actually trying not to use Primary or Qualifier.

I am new to stackOverflow so if there's any mistake / doubt , please tell me!!

Comment: Your controller requires an instance of `Coach` to be autowired. Your configuration provides two Beans of the type `Coach`. Spring does not know which is the correct one, hence you get that error. Why do you have 2 `@Bean` methods that return `Coach`?

Comment: Got that from gpt . 

isn't by doing this @Bean public demoController setDemoController() I had define the type of Coach ...

and how will I add @ autowired could show me

Comment: ok i got that we cant create two beans for coach but than how we can autowire democontroller with desired Coach type ,

suppose I want ansk user for the coach type they need to activate

Comment: That is what @Qualifier is for, to help Spring differentiate beans that use the same interface.

Comment: because you have @RestController on you controller class, so spring will try to instantiate an additional instance to the one returned by your bean method. but removing the annotation will remove the required magic for an actual rest controller, so you need to remove the bean method again.

Comment: generally @zawarudo is right -- you need to specify which instance you want to use. note that spring is intelligent enough to use the field/parameter name as a qualifier, saving you the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Generally @zawarudo is right -- you need to specify which instance you want to use.

Note that Spring is intelligent enough to use the field/parameter name as a qualifier, saving you the annotation. :)

```java
@RestController
public class DemoController {
    private Coach myCoach;

    @Autowired
    // parameter name qualifies which coach instance to use
    public DemoController(Coach fCoach){
        this.myCoach=fCoach;
    }

    @GetMapping("/demo")
    public String demo(){
        return myCoach.dailyWorkout();
    }


}
```